# I am not using slf4j in my code but still I am getting warnings related to it

Tags: java, spring-boot, log4j, slf4j

I am working with log4j but I am getting slf4j warnings while running my applications :

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
```

I am using these dependencies :

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Please help me getting rid of these warnings while starting my application.

Comment: Does your code have any reference to SLF4J?

Comment: mu guess: stop using those dependencies, and those warnings 'll be gone.
They don't hurt, they just inform, let them be.

Comment: https://mkyong.com/java/log4j2-failed-to-load-class-org-slf4j-impl-staticloggerbinder/

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen No, I don't

Comment: @Eritrean, Thanks a lot , it works for me. I wonder why I could not get this link at the first place.

Answer (score 0):

You can first remove those dependencies from your pom.xml, if its a maven project.
Then in the pom.xml directory run

```
maven clean compile
```

After, you can try it again.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's because of some third-party library that you have in your project, you can find the dependency of that in the dependency tree and exclude it from your project.